# Combine two arrays in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can I merge two arrays in JavaScript like this?

these arrays:

```
arr1 = ['one','two','three'];
arr2 = [1,2,3];
```

into

```
arr3 = ['one': 1, 'two': 2, 'three' : 3]
```

Comment: This isn't really an array *merge* as much as it is a *combine*.

Comment: You can do it manually in a simple for loop.

Comment: jQuery *is not a language*. Also, JavaScript doesn't have associative arrays, just objects.

Comment: What would be the point, if you could just reference two corresponding entries based on them sharing the same array index?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to merge two arrays in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1584370/how-to-merge-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Comment: @davidethell: That's not the same thing.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary yes you right I wanted say combine

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
var arr3 = {};
for (var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    arr3[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
}
```

Please note that `arr3` is not array, it is [object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Guide/Working_with_Objects).

Answer (score 8):

You can use `Array.prototype.reduce`...

```
var arr3 = arr1.reduce(function(obj, val, i) {
    obj[val] = arr2[i];
    return obj;
}, {});
```

***DEMO:*** http://jsfiddle.net/GMxcM/

```
{
    "one": 1,
    "two": 2,
    "three": 3
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just because you said `in jQuery`, here's a jQuery`$.each` version.

```
arr1 = ['one','two','three'];
arr2 = [1,2,3];
arr3 = {};
$.each(arr1, function(i, value){
  arr3[value] = arr2[i];
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(arr3));
```

**output** ->

```
{"one":1,"two":2,"three":3}
```

**[here's a working jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/qZT6n/)**

Answer (score 1):

Loop!

```
var arr1 = ['one','two','three'];
var arr2 = [1,2,3];
var result = {};

for(var i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
    result[arr1[i]] = arr2[i];
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Even easier:

```
$.merge(arr1, arr2);
```

Comment: This is not what he wants!