# How to merge two arrays into an object

Tags: jquery, arrays, object

```
    var eenhedennamen = ['unit1', 'unit2', 'unit3'];
    var value = [1,2,3];
```

What I'm trying to get:

```
     var newobject = {'unit1' : 1
                      'unit2': 2
                     'unit3' : 3};
```

How can I accomplish this?

Comment: Are the always in the same order? (Is `unit1` always `1` etc?

Comment: Yeah they always are :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Assuming these are parallel arrays (the first entry in `eenhedennamen` uses the first entry in `value`), you can loop through with jQuery's [`$.each`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each), which gives you the index and the entry for each entry, and build the object from the loop.

```
var obj = {};
$.each(eenhedennamen, function(index, entry) {
    obj[entry] = value[index];
});
```

This works because in JavaScript, you can access properties using either dot notation and a property name literal (`obj.foo = "bar"`), or *bracketed* notation with a *string* property name (`obj["foo"] = "bar"`). In the latter case, the string can be the result of any expression. So in the above, we're using `entry` as the property name, which will be each name in `eenhedennamen`. Then of course, we get the corresponding value from `value` using the `index`.

Comment: What if they are not in same order or value[] have different values?

Comment: @ssilas777: As I said above, the answer is contingent on them being parallel arrays, which the OP confirms they are. Otherwise, we would need to know what the mapping to apply is; the basic concept would be similar.

Answer (score 0):

```
var eenhedennamen = [ 'unit1', 'unit2', 'unit3' ];
var value = [ 1, 2, 3 ];
var z = new Array();
for ( var i = 0; i < eenhedennamen.length; i++) {
    z[eenhedennamen[i]]=value[i];
}
```

The previous answer is better.

Comment: There's no reason to use an array for `z`.

Comment: You wre right, no need. And as I say - your answer is better.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`Array.prototype.reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)

Try this:

```
var eenhedennamen = ['unit1', 'unit2', 'unit3'];
var value = [1,2,3];
var arr3 = eenhedennamen.reduce(function(obj, val, i) {
    obj[val] = value[i];
    return obj;
}, {});    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(arr3));
```

[Try in fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3Kn9/)

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487123/combine-two-arrays-in-javascript)