# how to add two arrays in one array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to merge two arrays data in one array format but getting empty array how to solve this please help me out this.

```
array1= ["hjghh", "hjghhs", "hjghhsjj"]
    0:
    0:"hjghh" 
    1:"hjghhs"
    2:"hjghhsjj"
    array2=["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD","data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD","data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"]
    0:
    0: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"
    1: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"
    2: "data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"
```

in array3 I want to display like this

```
    0:
    0:["hjghh","data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"]
    1:["hjghhs","data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"]
    2:["hjghhsjj","data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"]
```

`this.barcodetextone` is 1st array
`this.ShowImgoriginal` is 2nd array

```
let arr3:any=[];
this.barcodetextone.forEach((i) => {
    arr3.push(Object.assign({}, this.ShowImgoriginal[i]));
});

console.log(arr3);
```

Comment: Why use `Object.assign`? Just use `arr3 = this.barcodetextone.map((elem, i) => [elem, this.ShowImgoriginal[i]]);`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Combine two arrays in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11487123/combine-two-arrays-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the index in the first array to get the values for the second array and push an array with both:

```js
let array1 = ["hjghh", "hjghhs", "hjghhsjj"];
let array2 = ["data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD","data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD","data:image/jpeg;base64,/9j/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD"];
let result = [];

array1.forEach((i, index) => {
    result.push([i, array2[index]])
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You're welcome. You should accept the answer in case somebody has the same question in the future.

Answer (score -1):

```
    let arr1 = ['a','b','c']
    let arr2 = [1,3,51,51,2,1,0]
    let arr3 = [...arr1,...arr2]
    let zib = {}
    arr3.forEach((elem,index)=> {
        zib[index] = elem
    })
```

is this what you meant ?